# missing packages when building ros from source

Tags: ros, rosdep, ros-electric, rosmake, rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I try to [install](http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/Ubuntu/Source) and [build](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/BuildingPackages) ROS electric from source, rosdep complains about not being able to find certain packages. These packages are not in the Ubuntu repositories, so where am I supposed to get them?

One such package is `yaml-cpp0.2.6-dev`.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12431/missing-packages-when-building-ros-from-source/) by [tprk77](https://answers.ros.org/users/1566/tprk77/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-12-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I didn't have this problem, so you probably omitted an installation step or so. ROS repositories provide `yaml-cpp0.2.6-dev`, so if you cannot install it with

```
sudo apt-get install yaml-cpp0.2.6-dev
```

it means that you probably didn't set up your sources.list properly (read [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/Ubuntu), depending on your Ubuntu version). Remember to set up your keys and update apt-get's lists afterwards:

```
wget http://packages.ros.org/ros.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
```

Now `yaml-cpp0.2.6-dev` should be there for you.

---

Originally posted by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) with karma: 1079 on 2011-12-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tprk77](https://answers.ros.org/users/1566/tprk77/) on 2012-01-04**:
Thank you for adding this to the wiki.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-01-02**:
I've added it to the wiki page for source based installation. http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/Ubuntu/Source

**Comment by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on 2011-12-22**:
Actually I think this should be mentioned in the Wiki, or is it?

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-12-22**:
This is true.  Even when doing ROS completely from source, there are a few other packages outside of ROS that the ROS repositories provide.  So even when doing a source install, you have to add the repositories to apt.